# Soft Line Break in STS/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Does anyone know if it's possible to do a soft (no whitespace character) break, such that I can improve readability without introducing newlines into a JSP page I'm working on?

Using Springsource Tool Suite (based off of Eclipse).

Thanks!

Comment: I know that Eclipse editors do support soft wrapping, but this is considered an experimental feature and can only be turned on programmatically in custom editors.  Maybe someone else has a better answer for you, but from my understanding, there is no way.